# Copy links, title within <a> tag and date values from foreign website using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

It is possible by using Zend Request extract link, strings within  tags also data values from foreign site and copy all this to an array and echo it?

For example following website http://bills.ru/, extract from table below "события на долговом рынке", all data should be store in an array having following structure.

> id
>
> date
>
> title
>
> url

Or can somebody at least give some good example of implementation Zend Request?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using something like [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte) which not let you filter the html returned.

If you don't want to use additional libraries you can also use `Zend\Dom` to query the html from your `Request`.

Comment: Both are well documented. Please provide "[the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

Answer (score 0):

This is code i managed to make on following task and it works.

```
<?php
use Zend\Http\Client;
use Zend\Dom\Query;
/**
* Extracts date values, titles and links from block "события на долговом рынке" then save all date in 1   
 * array and prints it.
 * 
 * Using Zend\Http\Client to make connection to website and further manipulate with Zend\Dom\Query's CSS selectors
* to retrieve date values, link and titles within block "событья на долговом рынке". Three private method are used to 
* return values for each type and 1 public function used for retrieving 
*
* @var client is Zend\Http\Client object and makes connection using function setUri() with declared website
* @var response servers as getting response from requested website
* @var dom is a Zend\Dom\Query object that allows manipulating with Zend\Http\Client objects 
* @var results is a Zend\Dom\NodeList object made by using function execute()
* @var result used in foreach loop and for retrieving titles and url from a tag
* @var results_date same as @var results but for date values
* @var result_date same as @var result but for date values
* @var dateArray array where date values will be stored 
* @var valuesArray array where data will be stored and printed afterwards
* @var html used to story content from @var client
*/
class BILLS 
{
public $client;
public $response;
public $dom;
public $results;
public $result;
public $results_date;
public $result_date;
public $dateArray;
public $valuesArray;
public $html;
/**
 * When new object with following class is created an object Zend\Http\Client is created and set Uri attribute.   
 * A request is being done to this object and data is put into $html variable for further use.
 * @see client, response, html
 */
function __construct ()
{
    $this->client = new \Zend\Http\Client();
    $this->client->setUri('http://bills.ru');
    $this->client->send();
    $this->response = $this->client->getResponse();
    $this->html = $this->response->getBody();

}
/**
 * Returns date values within object 
 * @see result_date
 */ 
private function _date()
{  
    return $this->result_date->textContent;
}
/**
 * Returns text content within object 
 * @see result
 */ 
private function _title()
{
    return $this->result->textContent;
}
/**
 * Returns url within object 
 * @see result
 */ 
private function _url()
{
    return $this->result->getAttribute('href');
}
/**
 * If connection has no problems a new Query object is created and searched for a tags with class new. Then 
 * using a foreach loop found data is stored in array and printed to screen. Uses 3 private function for returning
 * values for each type that will be stored in array an printed afterwards.
 *
 * @see dom, results_date, dateArray, results, valuesArray, _date(), _url(), _title()
 * 
 */
public function printTask()
{
    $iteration = 0;
    $iterationData = 0;
    if($this->response->getStatusCode() == 200)
    {
        $this->dom = new Query($this->html);
        $this->results_date = $this->dom->execute('table tr  td.news');

        foreach ($this->results_date as $this->result_date) 
        {
            if($iterationData < 5)
            {
               $dateArray[$iterationData] = $this->_date();
               $iterationData++;
            }
        }
        $this->results = $this->dom->execute('table  tr  td  a.news');

        foreach ($this->results as $this->result) 
        {
            if($iteration < 5)
            {
             $valuesArray = array(
                    'id' => $iteration+1,
                    'date' => $dateArray[$iteration],
                    'title' => $this->_title(),
                    'url' => "http://bills.ru".$this->_url()
                    );

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($valuesArray);
            echo  '</pre>';
                $iteration++;
            }   
        }
    } 
}
}
$object = new BILLS;
$object->printTask();
?>
```